# Direct 3D 11 Rasterizer Desc Error

Tags: c++, directx

for starters, I am a complete novice with D3D11, so I apologize for my ignorance in advance.

For my games programming module I am trying to render my cubes in a wireframe format.

I have followed my lecturers' code exactly and cannot figure out what is causing the following error.

On the line "hr = _pd3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&wfdesc, &_wireFrame);".

I get the error that &wfDesc is of type Application::"D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC", is not compatible with parameter of type, "const D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC".

//Wireframe creation............................................

```
D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC wfdesc;
ZeroMemory(&wfdesc, sizeof(D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC));
wfdesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME;
wfdesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
hr = _pd3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&wfdesc, &_wireFrame);
_pImmediateContext->RSSetState(_wireFrame);
ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetState;
```

//Wireframe creation............................................

Any ideas? My apologies for the poor asking etiquette.

Comment: How did you define `_wireFrame`? And did you by any chance define a `D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC` struct in your `Application` namespace? Would you copy/paste the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but after a good amount of trial and error I managed to sort it out. Thanks all the same.

The issue was that I defined wfdesc inside an initializer method. This caused a parameter mismatch, so I just declared it outside the method instead.